# How to get a x,y coordinates of cell within a WPF grid by column and row index

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, grid

I have a grid where I progamaticly add rowdefinitions and col definitions.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid Name="layoutGrid" ></Grid>
    <Canvas Name="overlayedCanvas"></Canvas>
</Grid>
```

.

```
// create rows
for (int r = 0; r < rowCount; r++)
    layoutGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = GridLength.Auto});
// create columns
for (int c = 0; c < colCount; c++)
    layoutGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition {Width = GridLength.Auto});
```

Then I place my usercontrols in some of the cells.
Grid gets auto resized based on individual user control sizes.

My goal is to draw a polygon connecting some of the cells.
e.g. It could be a Rect(1,1,3,3) starting in top left corner of cells[1,1]  down to bottom right corner of cells[3,3].
I was thinking of using this approach [access children by x,y coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3529788/how-to-access-children-in-grid-with-x-y-coordinates-instead-of-index) but I would have to create dummy controls within each cell.

Then I could calculate cell position:

```
Point topLeft = uc.TranslatePoint(new Point(0,0), layoutGrid);
Point bottomRight = uc.TranslatePoint(new Point(uc.ActualWidth, uc.ActualHeight), layoutGrid);
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private delegate void LoadDelegate();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        LoadDelegate oD = Load;
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke (
            oD,  
            System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Loaded, 
            null
        );
    }

    private void Load()
    {
        var items = LogicalTreeHelper
                        .GetChildren(uiGrid)
                        .OfType<Border>()
                        .Select(brd => new { Column = Grid.GetColumn(brd), Row = Grid.GetRow(brd), Item = brd })
                        .ToList();
        Border oStart = items
                            .FirstOrDefault(item => item.Column == 1 && item.Row == 1)
                            .Item;
        Border oStop = items
                            .FirstOrDefault(item => item.Column == 2 && item.Row == 2)
                            .Item;

        Point topLeft = oStart.PointToScreen(new Point(0, 0));
        Point bottomRight = oStop.PointToScreen(new Point(oStop.ActualWidth, oStop.ActualHeight));

        Rectangle oRect = new Rectangle();
        oRect.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(0, 255, 0));

        Point oLeft = uiCanvas.PointFromScreen(topLeft);
        Canvas.SetLeft(oRect, oLeft.X);
        Canvas.SetTop(oRect, oLeft.Y);
        oRect.Width = bottomRight.X - topLeft.X;
        oRect.Height = bottomRight.Y - topLeft.Y;

        uiCanvas.Children.Add(oRect);
    }
}
```

...

```
<Grid>
    <Grid x:Name="uiGrid">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Border Background="Red" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" />
        <Border Background="Red" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" />
    </Grid>

    <Canvas x:Name="uiCanvas" />
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Get dimensions as [Rect[ , ]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.rect) for all cells in a WPF [Grid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.grid):

> Returns current runtime dimensions for **all cells** in a WPF `Grid`, as reported by [RowDefinition.​ActualHeight](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.rowdefinition.actualheight) and [ColumnDefinition.ActualWidth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.columndefinition.actualwidth). Results are returned in a 2-dimensional array `Rect[row,column]`. For example, the `Point` value [Rect.BottomRight](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.rect.bottomright) for the last element in the returned array will equal the [RenderSize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.uielement.rendersize) of the `Grid` at the time of the call.

```
public static Rect[,] GetCellRects(this Grid grid) =>
                      GetCellRects(grid.RowDefinitions, grid.ColumnDefinitions);

static Rect[,] GetCellRects(RowDefinitionCollection rows, ColumnDefinitionCollection cols)
{
    int i = rows.Count, j = cols.Count;
    var a = new Rect[i, j];
    if (i > 0 && j > 0)
    {
        Double x;
        for (i = a.GetLength(0); --i >= 0;)
            for (x = rows[i].ActualHeight, j = a.GetLength(1); --j >= 0;)
                a[i, j].Height = x;

        for (j = a.GetLength(1); --j >= 0;)
            for (x = cols[j].ActualWidth, i = a.GetLength(0); --i >= 0;)
                a[i, j].Width = x;

        for (i = 0; i < a.GetLength(0); i++)
            for (j = 0; j < a.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                if (j > 0)
                    a[i, j].X = a[i, j - 1].Right;
                if (i > 0)
                    a[i, j].Y = a[i - 1, j].Bottom;
            }
    }
    return a;
}
```

<sub>As an aside, this code employs one of the classic [Dynamic Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) canonical examples. Here, the benefit is that each `ActualHeight` and `ActualWidth` property is accessed *only once* per row or column (respectively), this number obviously being minimal. It is a fun exercise to try to devise alternatives to the code shown here which preserve that behavior. Or instead, convince yourself why the final nested loops can't proceed in reverse, like the earlier loops do…?</sub>